# Filter date column starting from sunday

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a dataframe with a date column as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
                id = c(1, 2, 4, 65, 77, 5, 4),
              date = c("2020-04-18", "2020-04-20", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-19",
                       "2020-04-02", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-20")
      ) %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date))
```

I would like to systematically filter the date column with elements antecedent to the last Sunday.

Today is `2020-04-20`, and it's a Monday. 
The first Sunday is `2020-04-19`

```
last_sunday <- as.Date(`2020-04-19`)

df %>% filter(date <= last_sunday)

  id       date
1  1 2020-04-18
2  4 2020-04-01
3 65 2020-04-19
4 77 2020-04-02
5  5 2020-04-01
```

How can I programmatically define the variable "last_sunday".

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 filter(date <= min(date[as.POSIXlt(date)$wday == 0]))

  id       date
1  1 2020-04-18
2  4 2020-04-01
3 65 2020-04-19
4 77 2020-04-02
5  5 2020-04-01
```

Answer (score 0):

using `lubridate`

```
previous_sunday <- lubridate::floor_date(Sys.Date(), "week")

previous_sunday
[1] "2020-04-19"

df %>% filter(date <= previous_sunday)
  id       date
1  1 2020-04-18
2  4 2020-04-01
3 65 2020-04-19
4 77 2020-04-02
5  5 2020-04-01
```